# how to run JavaScript code in typescript component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in angular and working in angular 5 (typescript) project and i need a JSON validator function, i got a function from internet but it is in purely JavaScript.

I want that function in my component, it actually checks that given JSON is in correct format or not.

```
<textarea ng-change="updateJsonObject()" ng-model="script" rows="10" 
 class="form-control" style="width: 100%" ng-style="formatting">
```

```
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
  $scope.formatting = {color: 'green', 'background-color':'#d0e9c6'};
  $scope.message = {
                BasketCost: '5.00',
                Fruit: ['Apple', 'Orange', {Name: 'Pear', Expires: '15/05/17'}],
  };

  $scope.isValid = true;

  $scope.script = JSON.stringify($scope.message);

  $scope.updateJsonObject = function() {
    try {
      JSON.parse($scope.script);
    } catch (e) {
      $scope.isValid = false;
      $scope.formatting = {color: 'red', 'background-color':'#f2dede'};
    }

    $scope.message = JSON.parse($scope.script);
    $scope.isValid = true;
    $scope.formatting = {color: 'green', 'background-color':'#d0e9c6'};
  };
});
```

what is the way to add this code in my component.ts,

Comment: That should be a fairly easy task, it's converting AngularJs code to Angular. Cf. https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow url  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8jjx4b

**ngModelChange** you need to use ngModelChange for reflecting the changes immediately.

```
<textarea (change)="updateJsonObject()" (ngModelChange)="updateJsonObject()" [(ngModel)]="script" rows="10" 
 class="form-control" style="width: 100%" [ngStyle]="formatting"></textarea>
```

//   in class

```
  message = {
    BasketCost: '5.00',
    Fruit: ['Apple', 'Orange', { Name: 'Pear', Expires: '15/05/17' }],
  };

  isValid = true;

  // script = '{' + JSON.stringify(this.message) + ')'; // testing
  script = JSON.stringify(this.message) ;


  formatting = { color: 'green', 'background-color': '#d0e9c6' };


  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateJsonObject();
  }

  updateJsonObject() {
    try {
      JSON.parse(this.script);
      this.formatting = {color: 'green', 'background-color':'#d0e9c6'};
      console.log('invalid');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('invalid');
      this.isValid = false;
      this.formatting = {color: 'red', 'background-color':'#f2dede'};
    }
  }
```

Comment: It works fine but there is a little issue, when I lose the focus i mean when the field is untouched then the error occurs if any

Comment: yes..that case we are handling inside ngOnInit. Or if you expecting any api call to resolve its better to call updateJsonObject inside the resposne block

Comment: its already there.  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateJsonObject();
  }

Comment: Yea, thats why we are suing ngmodelchange

Comment: ok i got it, just need this modifications (ngModelChange)="updateJsonObject($event)" and not need for (change) event